# Is creating graph charts on server and accessing it from client is bad design?

Tags: java, apache-flex

Suppose we have two choices for creating charts as follows:

1. Creating charts on server side (Java) through some open source library say jfreecharts and sending the images to client
2. Creating graph charts at client side (Flex) and displaying them. Please note that there are almost no open source  flex libraries available for creating various charts. Either option is to buy expensive libraries or to write one.

What will be most preferable way and why?

Comment: Depends.  If the graph is non-interactive, then no, I wouldn't consider it bad design.  The question you need to asks, is downloading the image more or less intensive then the client machine creating accessing the data over the network and generating it themselves.  Then there is the question of resources.  Is the server better suited (powerful) to the task or is it going to be drain on it's resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response-latency will increase if the chart or image generated is of greater size than the original xml or json that is being used to create it.

If a large amount of data transfer is involved, always prefer a meaningful format like a JSON string or an xml and process it on client side.